# How to select only a few items for a table in HTML using JavaScript Array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, datatables

I'm getting data from an API and I want to display this data in a table with 3 columns and dynamic rows- that's because of the API data

I have this code here:

```
})
                })
        //console.log(await response.json())
            const balancestoken = await response.json()
           
            function generateTableHead(table, data) {
            let thead = table.createTHead();
            let row = thead.insertRow();
            for (let key of data) {
                let th = document.createElement("th");
                let text = document.createTextNode(key);
                th.appendChild(text);
                row.appendChild(th);
            }
            }

            function generateTable(table, data) {
            for (let element of data) {
                let row = table.insertRow();
                for (key in element) {
                let cell = row.insertCell();
                let text = document.createTextNode(element[key]);
                cell.appendChild(text);
                }
            }
            }

            let table = document.querySelector("table");
            let data = Object.keys(balancestoken[0]);
            generateTableHead(table, data);
            generateTable(table, balancestoken);
                    }
```

When using this code I get following output(table):

```
token_address   name    symbol  logo    thumbnail   decimals    balance 0x925841cf448a6c350bd19a7a0bdff93da9760a53  SafeCoom    SAFECOOM    null    null    9   108221437157689 0xf68c9df95a18b2a5a5fa1124d79eeeffbad0b6fa  Anyswap-BEP20   ANY null    null    18  1000000000000000000 0xd22202d23fe7de9e3dbe11a2a88f42f4cb9507cf  Minereum BSC    MNEB    null    null    8   15000000000000 0x373233a38ae21cf0c4f9de11570e7d5aa6824a1e   ALPACAFIN.COM   ALPACA  null    null    18  28102000000000000000000000
```

This are the columns I get:
token_address   name    symbol  logo    thumbnail   decimals    balance

Which is the default response by the API

How can I select only token_address, symbol and balance and display them in my table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add conditional expression for key.
Here is the code:

```
function generateTableHead(table, data) {
  let thead = table.createTHead();
  let row = thead.insertRow();
  for (let key of data) {
    // add this expression
    if (key == "token_address" || key == "symbol" || key == "balance") 
    {
      let th = document.createElement("th");
      let text = document.createTextNode(key);
      th.appendChild(text);
      row.appendChild(th);
    }
  }
}

function generateTable(table, data) {
  for (let element of data) {
    let row = table.insertRow();
    for (key in element) {
      // add this expression
      if (key == "token_address" || key == "symbol" || key == "balance") {
        let cell = row.insertCell();
        let text = document.createTextNode(element[key]);
        cell.appendChild(text);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ok this works, but isnt there a better way to map over this array and display it in a bootstrap table